# Create AChartEngine TimeChart using Time in Y-Axis

Tags: java, android, time, achartengine

I have some data representing answered questions in particular time e.g.

Question 1 answered in 00:00:20.
I am trying to use AChartEngine to represent this but with no luck.
First of all I can't have Y values as this format for a reason, guess it's not supported or needs customization which couldn't find a way till now to achieve.

My chart should have in the end the X-Axis with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... and Y-Axis with
00:00:20, 00:00:15, 00:00:05, 00:00:10....
The time achieved in each question is saved in a Time object field.
I try this approach:

```
private void fillData() {
        int i = 0;
        for (Answer answer : getAnswers()) {
            i++;
            if (answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
                myQuestionsTimeSeries.add(new Date(DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime())), i);
            }
        }
    }
```

First problem, can't get the time values to Y-Axis and not shown correctly anyway. See screenshot below.

[image]

I guess you get my point so far.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: the Y axis that use some weird transformation between a number and a time. I would give you the exact values if I had them, but this code is back on my old company. But hopefully that hint can help you Google your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TimeChart displays formatted date labels on the X axis. It seems like you need to do that on the Y axis.

Just create a regular LineChart and add custom labels on the Y axis:

```
// disable the default Y labels first
renderer.setYLabels(0);
// add several custom labels
renderer.addYTextLabel(y, "label");
```

Comment: hmmm, will try it and get back to you with some code. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Can you show an example using this and the Series.add(x, y) method?

Comment: Thank you i think I made it half work, you can check my next problem and the state of the chart at the moment in this new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070059/create-achartengine-timechart-using-time-in-y-axis