# AChartEngine Y-Axis custom labels area margins and chart values as String?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I have created a Chart shows Questions (X) / Time (Y) answered during a test.
You can see the first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070059/create-achartengine-timechart-using-time-in-y-axis) for details.

But now I need to show the chart bullet values correctly, at the moment shows the milliseconds value but i need to show the custom hh:mm:ss value like I've done with the Y-Axis label and somehow customize the Y-Axis area to show the full values correctly. 
Below is a screenshot of how the chart looks like now.

[image: Chart Questions / Etsimated Answered Time]

[EDIT]

With Dan's help I almost got what I want. It's just a little problem.
Check in the screenshot below where the chart values now appearing.
I updated to 1.1.0 from the AChartEngine repository.
addNotations is on the TimeSeries objects. I copy paste my code below where adding data to my TimeSeries instance.

```
myQuestionsTimeSeries.add(i, DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
                xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.addYTextLabel(DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()),
                        String.valueOf(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
                myQuestionsTimeSeries.addAnnotation(String.valueOf(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()), i,
                        DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
```

The code results to this Chart:

[image: My Chart at the moment]

[EDIT]

This is basically the whole class:

```
private void initQuestionsTimeChart() {
        xyMultipleSeriesDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        questionsTimeChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), xyMultipleSeriesDataset, xyMultipleSeriesRenderer);
        rootView.addView(questionsTimeChart);

        initSeriesData();
    }

    private void initSeriesData() {
        createMyQuestionsSeries();
        addSeriesAndRenderer(myQuestionsTimeSeries, myQuestionsRenderer);

        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYTitle("Questions Time");
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setXTitle("Questions Number");
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYLabels(0);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 80, 80, 80, 80 });
    }

    private void addSeriesAndRenderer(XYSeries series, XYSeriesRenderer renderer) {
        xyMultipleSeriesDataset.addSeries(series);
        xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    }

    private void createMyQuestionsSeries() {
        myQuestionsTimeSeries = new TimeSeries("My Questions/Time");
        myQuestionsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        myQuestionsRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myQuestionsRenderer.setLineWidth(3f);
        myQuestionsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        myQuestionsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        myQuestionsRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(10f);
    }

    private void fillData() {
        int i = 0;
        for (Answer answer : getAnswers()) {
            i++;
            if (answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime() != null) {
                myQuestionsTimeSeries.add(i, DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
                xyMultipleSeriesRenderer.addYTextLabel(DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()),
                        String.valueOf(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
                myQuestionsTimeSeries.addAnnotation(String.valueOf(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()), i,
                        DateTimeHelper.getMillisFromTime(answer.getEstimatedAnswerTime()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, hide the chart values:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
```

Then, for each chart value, add an annotation:

```
renderer.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```

For the Y axis labels to be visible, just align them to LEFT:

```
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
```

Or you can increase the margins:

```
renderer.setMargins(margins);
```

Make sure you are using the latest ACE build available [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: Thank you Dan, almost there, check my edited question for the last problem I have with the chart values, they're not where they supposed to, for a reason!

Comment: Don't use TimeSeries, use XYSeries.

Comment: Same problem, nothing actually changed!

Comment: Hard to guess what is going on from the 3 lines of code you have posted.

Comment: I uploaded the whole fragment class in this link http://rapidshare.com/files/3229453778/ResultsChartFragment.java

Comment: "Download not available". Anyway, don't upload anything. Just post a piece of code that replicates the issue and I can use for debugging.

Comment: OK, I have posted the methods about the chart.

Comment: I found a bug in annotation rendering and fixed it. Please download an updated version here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/